# Unable to write the custom CSS for sharepoint 2013 app

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, app

I have added the SharePoint app from SharePoint 2013 App store.Also added that app in the custom page. I need to write the external CSS for that APP part.I have added the custom style sheet in the custom master page.but custom CSS not reflected in page.please suggest your idea.

Comment: can you please add this custom css in app then try it...

Comment: I added the out of the box app. So , i can't add custom CSS in app.

Comment: this depends on the app. Which app are you refering to?

Comment: For Quick poll app in SharePoint store